# Running Remote Desktop over port 443

Tags: iis, ssl, remote, desktop

I have a server hosted behind a bunch of firewalls, and it is accessible to me only on ports 80 and 443.

The hosting company is pretty sluggish wrt support, so I would like a way to get a remote desktop to the computer.

Is it possible to install a webapp or something that would allow me to get a remote desktop via the ssl port for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the machine to **connect to**:

1. Start Registry Editor.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber`
3. On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.
4. Type the new port number (443), and then click OK.
5. Quit Registry Editor.

On the machine to **connect from**:

1. Start Remote Desktop Client.
2. Enter IP address or hostname of the target machine and append with ':443', e.g. 10.1.210.119:443
3. Continue login like usual.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759

---

Or you can set up Remote Desktop web app by following instructions at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/northrup_03may16.mspx

Answer (score 0):

MS Directions for [XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759) or [Configuring XP WebApp](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/northrup_03may16.mspx), [Terminal Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187623), [TS Web App](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326945); and Petri directions for the [Client](http://www.petri.co.il/use_rdp_client_to_connect_to_a_different_port.htm).